# Получить Tile из Tilemap, если объект это prefab

Tags: unity3d, tilemap

Написал скрипт, который из Tilemap генерирует матрицу проходимости (он ищет объект с TilemapRenderer и TilemapCollider2D, проходит по каждой ячейке, и если там есть тайл, то информация об этом заносится в матрицу проходимости).

Скрипт отлично работает, если TieMap находится на сцене. Но у меня очень много таких объектов в папке проекта (в виде префабов). Я хотел, с помощью контекстного меню, вызвать написанную функцию и инициализировать все префабы соответствующими матрицами. Однако, код, написанный для получения тайлов, не работает, если объекта нет на сцене.

Вот этот кусок кода:

```
Vector3 worldPos = 
    transform.position // позиция объекта с TileMap на сцене
    + new Vector3(col, row) * MapBlock.BLOCK_SCALE; // положение клетки внутри объекта с TileMap

var tile = tilemap.GetTile(tilemap.WorldToCell(worldPos));
if (tile != null)
    block.CellRows[row].Row[col] = true;
```

В общем, как я понял, полученные мировые координаты не корректны для объекта, которого нет на сцене.
Тогда как мне получить тайлы? Каким образом нужно рассчитывать координаты тайлов и передавать их в метод `tilemap.GetTile()`?

p.s. `tilemap.LocalToCell()` я пробовал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, нужно было передать напрямую индексы ячеек.

```
var tile = tilemap.GetTile(
    new Vector3Int(col - MapBlock.BLOCK_SIZE / 2, row - MapBlock.BLOCK_SIZE / 2, 0)
);
```

`MapBlock.BLOCK_SIZE` - размер сетки TileMap

Конечно, пришлось помучатся, пока понял как расположены ячейки соответственно их индексам....

Для 2D, индекс по Z **обязательно** указать равным **0**